# SQL server DB connectivity issue for application server restart

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

I have configured 2 applications Database in single SQL Server 2017 .Whenever restart one application server the other application server connectivity also break down from DB and causes application shout down issue.

The below logs getting from one of the shout down server.

> executeBatchUpdate - SQL Exception msg : java.net.SocketException:
> Connection reset executeBatchUpdate - SQL State : 08S01
> executeBatchUpdate - SQL Error Code : 0
> <-----------------executeBatchUpdate - Exception Info - End --------->
> INFO  JDBCService - Unable to free connection back to pool. Error: The
> connection is closed. WARN  RecoverableDAO - Exception while setting
> the Auto commit level back to original setting. Message:The connection
> is closed. INFO  JDBCService - Unable to free connection back to pool.
> Error: The connection is closed. WARN  RecoverableDAO - Exception
> while setting the Auto commit level back to original setting.
> Message:The connection is closed. INFO  JDBCService - Unable to free
> connection back to pool. Error: The connection is closed. WARN
> RecoverableDAO - Exception while setting the Auto commit level back to
> original setting. Message:The connection is closed. INFO  JDBCService
>
> - Unable to free connection back to pool. Error: The connection is closed. WARN  RecoverableDAO - Exception while setting the Auto commit
>   level back to original setting. Message:The connection is closed. INFO
>   RecoverableDAO -  <----------------- executeBatchUpdate - Exception
>   Info - Begin --------> executeBatchUpdate - SQL cmd :UPDATE CC_SERVER
>   SET DESCRIPTION = ?, LAST_CHECKIN = ?, MODIFICATION_DATE = ?,
>   DISPLAY_NAME = ?, STATUS = ?, HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL = ?, LOCATION = ?,
>   PROPERTIES = ?, STATUS_MESSAGE = ?, STATUS_MESSAGE_ID = ?,
>   LAST_HEARTBEAT_EVENT = ?, HOST_NAME = ?, PORT = ?, SECURE_HOST_NAME =
>   ?, SECURE_PORT = ?, TIMEZONE_ID = ?, USES_SNMP_TRAP = ?,
>   MONITORED_SVR_REASSIGN_POLICY = ?, SERVER_OS = ?, SERVER_VERSION = ?,
>   SERVER_BUILD_VERSION = ?, MODIFIED_BY = ?, NETMAP_NODE_ACCESS = ?,
>   NETMAP_MODE_ACCESS = ?, NETMAP_COMMPATH_ACCESS = ?, INITPARMS_ACCESS =
>   ?, USER_AUTH_ACCESS = ?, USER_PROXY_ACCESS = ?, TRANSLATE_TABLE_ACCESS
>   = ?, SPLUS_KEYCERT_ACCESS = ?, SPLUS_TRUSTEDCERT_ACCESS = ?, SPLUS_CIPHER_ACCESS = ?, SPLUS_NODE_ACCESS = ?, SPLUS_PARMFILE_ACCESS
>   = ?, MGMT_OBJECT_TYPES = ?, NODE_NAME = ?, NOT_MANAGED = ?, NOT_MONITORED = ?, IGNORE_SERVER_PROVIDED_TZ = ?, PROTOCOL = ?,
>   CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = ?, SECURE_PLUS_ENABLED = ?, SNMP_LISTENER_ADDRESS
>   = ?, SNMP_LISTENER_PORT = ?, WEB_SERVICE_PORT = ?, METADATA_1 = ?, METADATA_2 = ?, METADATA_3 = ?, METADATA_4 = ?, METADATA_5 = ?,
>   METADATA_6 = ?, METADATA_7 = ?, METADATA_8 = ?, METADATA_9 = ?,
>   METADATA_10 = ? WHERE SERVER_ID = ? AND MODIFICATION_DATE = ?
>   ([ServerToUpdate: EFX_UK_UAT_CDUNIX(204, READY)  NotifyLocalListeners:
>   true  GenerateClusterEvent: false]) executeBatchUpdate - SQL Exception
>   msg : java.net.SocketException: Connection reset executeBatchUpdate -
>   SQL State : 08S01 executeBatchUpdate - SQL Error Code : 0
>   <-----------------executeBatchUpdate - Exception Info - End --------->
>   INFO  JDBCService - Unable to free connection back to pool. Error: The
>   connection is closed. WARN  RecoverableDAO - Exception while setting
>   the Auto commit level back to original setting. Message:The connection
>   is closed. ERROR SQLExceptionShutdownHandler - **
>   SQLExceptionShutdownHandler entered with
>   sqlex=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException:
>   java.net.SocketException: Connection reset ERROR
>   SQLExceptionShutdownHandler - ** Event not updated or details on what
>   was being done when error occurred -> java.net.SocketException:
>   Connection reset ERROR SQLExceptionShutdownHandler -
>   java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
>   Stack Trace:
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
>   at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(SQLServerConnection.java:2924)
>   ERROR SQLExceptionShutdownHandler - ** sqlex not null, showing stack
>   trace: ERROR SQLExceptionShutdownHandler - ** About to broadcast
>   CJDB026E, which will cause engine to shut down ... ERROR
>   SCCEventHandler - CCTR089E Engine shutdown has been initiated ...
>   [Thread-12661] INFO  JettyServerStopper - Running UNIX/LINUX platform
>   stopper script.../installdirectory/application/bin/stopWebAppServer.sh
>   [StreamConsumerThread - CMD] INFO  StreamConsumer - CMD OUT-->Web
>   server is running...initiating shutdown... [ProcessSummary] INFO
>   ConnectionPool - Created a new connection in pool default
>   [StreamConsumerThread - CMD] INFO  StreamConsumer - CMD OUT-->Exit
>   code :  0 [StreamConsumerThread - CMD] INFO  StreamConsumer - CMD
>   OUT-->Web server is still running...will wait for 5 seconds(up to 15
>   times)... [StreamConsumerThread - CMD] INFO  StreamConsumer - CMD
>   OUT-->Web server has been stopped ...

Comment: Do the two applications interact with each other in any way?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the quick response..
Yes, The SFG application and the ICC monitoring application both are interacting.

Comment: In what way do they interact with each other?...i.e. is one dependent on the other, for it's data connection perhaps? Which application is restarted first?

Comment: The SFG server is the main server and the ICC server is monitoring the SFG server activities. The both server connect through http protocol.
Whenever the SFG server restart the other server ICC also went down(The both servers DB are configured in the same SQL server)..

Comment: Are you running the two applications on the same web server? Is there are server clustering involved on application or database servers? If so, please describe the clustering configuration as well.

Comment: The main error being reported in that call stack is that the connection to the server was lost, and thus your Java app isn't able to get a connection from the connection pool. (Can't swim if the pool is closed!) It's important to identify why the connection is being closed, but it's also important to ensure that applications have logic to automatically reconnect if existing connections drop. _Failure to include reconnect logic means that even if the database is only unavailable for a moment, your app may still crash and need a full restart.

Comment: The SFG server only have cluster configuration. As per the understanding the JDBC pool is not reset after the SFG server restart in DB and once the SFG server is restart the JDBC pool is fully occupies by the SFG server after the ICC server went down..
Is there any way to reset the jdbc connection pool for ICC server after the restart?